# PHP search is showing entire db table when opening page

Tags: php, mysql, search, space

When I open my search page,

(1) it immediately shows all results (every entry in my db.)

(2) It also shows every entry in my db when search button is clicked with empty input.

How do I resolve this? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">


<input type="text" name="k" size="50" value="<?php echo $_GET['k']; ?>"/>

<input type="submit" value="search" />


</form>
<hr color="white">

<?php

$k = $_GET['k'];
$terms = explode(" ", $k);

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ";

foreach ($terms as $each) {
    $i++;

    if ($i == 1)
        $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
    else
        $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
}

//connect
mysql_connect("localhost", "abc", "pass");
mysql_select_db("mydb");


$query = mysql_query($query);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($numrows > 0) {

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $link = $row['link'];
        $picture = $row['picture'];
        $keywords = $row['keywords'];
        $date = $row['date'];


    echo $row['title'];

    }

}
else
    echo "No results found for \"<b>$k</b>\"";

//disconnect
mysql_close();



?>
```

Comment: Check to see if there is any input - `if (! empty($_GET['k'])) {`

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack vulnerability](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your database pwn3d.

Comment: Well, SQL Injection might still be applicable here I think... At least single quotes can break your code... @MarcB : there is a split on " " in there, so it doesn't seem that easy to do in the DB itself..

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely in the first couple of lines:

```
$k = $_GET['k'];
$terms = explode(" ", $k);

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE ";

foreach ($terms as $each) {
    $i++;

    if ($i == 1)
        $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
    else
        $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
}
```

Check your `$terms` array after the `explode(" ", $k)` and the `$query` before you run it. You'll have to check to make sure the `$each` element is not empty in your foreach statement, at least.

Explode is probably putting empty items in your query, so you have:

```
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE keywords LIKE '%%'`
```

Which will make any other `OR keywords LIKE` useless.

Answer (score 0):

Some obligatory, *boilerplate answering* here:

1. you have a **security issue.** You should always sanitize the input you put into a query! Take a look at **[SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)**
2. mysql_* is **deprecated** as of PHP 5.5. Use [**mysqli_***](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead

**And now the issue...**

You always add a

```
"keywords LIKE '%%' ";
```

clause to the query. Why? The first invocation of the page means there is **no** GET parameter named k. And this line:

```
$terms = explode(" ", $k);
```

returns an array of length 1, containing one empty string literal...

Also, with an **empty string** given as search condition, guess what you get: the same situation...